# Iterating over Map containing String and List of String using jstl foreach

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying to iterate over a Map containing list of  mobiles and list of prices.I am getting the mobiles and prices in jsp page but unable to produce output in correct fromat. I want output as follows

Mobile 1
price
Mobile 2
price

But I am getting op as

mobile mobile
price price

controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/demo")
public ModelAndView demo() {
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("demo");
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> price=new ArrayList<String>();
    phone.add("iphone");
    phone.add("nokia");
    price.add("70000");
    price.add("20000");
    map.put("mobile",phone);
    map.put("price",price);
    model.addObject("student", map);
    return model;
}
```

jsp code

```
<c:forEach  var="s" items="${student}">
  <c:forEach var="s1" items="${s.value }" varStatus="loop">
    ${s1}
     </br>
  </c:forEach> 
   <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Why is your map consisting of a `List<String>`? Having a `Map<String, String>` which represents `<phone, price>` is sufficient enough, why are you complicating this with lists?

Comment: actually i m creating shopping cart where my map consist of list of product name,list of product prices,list of product description, and list of product images , all fetched from database.i just crated this simple example to solve my query.

Comment: Using a map for doing something like that doesn't seem optimal, why not use an object? Get items from a database into the format of an `Item` object and add it to a `Cart` where `Cart` has `List<Item>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer.code in controller will remain same.

jsp code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="i" value="0" scope="page" />

<c:forEach  var="item" items="${student['mobile']}" varStatus="status">
  <div>

 <c:out value="${student['mobile'][i]}"></c:out>
              ${student['price'][i]};
              <c:set var="i" value="${i+1}" scope="page" />
  </div>
  </c:forEach> 
<body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help you

#### Create a POJO Bean

```
 public class ItemModel{
    private String mobile;
    private int price;

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile= mobile;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price= price;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
 }
```

#### Modify your Controller Part

```
@RequestMapping(value="/demo")
public ModelAndView demo() {
   ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("demo");
   List<ItemModel> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemModel>();

   ItemModel item1 = new ItemModel();
   item1.setMobile("iphone");
   item1.setPrice(55000);

   ItemModel item2 = new ItemModel();
   item2.setMobile("nokia");
   item2.setPrice(20000);

   itemList.add(item1);
   itemList.add(item2);

   model.addObject("student", itemList);

   return model;
}
```

#### Client Side:

```
<c:forEach  var="s" items="${student}">
  Mobile=${s.mobile}
  Price=${s.price}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way to iterate over a map(i have tested this code)

```
<c:forEach items="${model}" var="element">
<p>Key</p> <c:out value="${element.key}"></c:out>
<p>Value</p><c:out value="${element.value}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

in servlet /controller(for spring change accordingly)

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        map.put(1, "Java");
        map.put(2, "for");
        map.put(1, "fun");
        request.setAttribute("model", map);
```